# Incorrect results obtained in simple arithmetic using php

Tags: php, addition, subtraction

Here is a simple PHP script:

```
<?php
  $a = 100;
  $b = 91.51;
  $c = 8.49;

  $d = $a - $b - $c;
  echo $d;
?>
```

It outputs  -5.3290705182008E-15 which is ugly
With minor change as follows:

```
  $d = $a - ($b + $c);
  echo $d;
?>
```

The output is 0 which is correct. Why is this happening?

Comment: Floating point.  Need I say more?

Comment: Yes please. Just a little more

Comment: @RaoufAthar take a look here http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Output is correct in both cases. You have to use special functions if you want to format it

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **number_format** like this:

```
  $a = 100;

  $b = number_format(91.51, 0, ".", "." );

  $c = number_format(8.49, 0, ".", "." );

  $d = $a - $b - $c;

  echo $d;
```

Answer (score 3):

Floating point maths is actually very inaccurate.  It's a "best guess" value ;)

In floating point (single precision) 100 - 91.51 is not 8.49 as you would expect, but 8.4899978638 since the value 8.49 cannot be exactly expressed in floating point.  With double precision it gets better, as it equates to 8.48999999999999488409 which is a little closer.  Still not exact though.

Take the following code example:

```
echo (100 - 91.51) . "\n";
echo number_format(100 - 91.51, 20) . "\n";
```

The output of that you would expect to be

```
8.49
8.49000000000000000000
```

But in fact it is:

```
8.49
8.48999999999999488409
```

It defaults to rounding to 2 decimal places for printing floating point values.

Floating point is very much a trade-off.  It is a numerical representation system that provides increased resolution and range at the cost of accuracy.  For accuracy, but with limited resolution and range, fixed point arithmetic is often used.   For instance, if you were storing voltage values between 0V and 5V and you wanted precise measurements at 1µV resolution (i.e., 0.000001V divisions) you may choose to instead represent your voltages in microvolts not volts, so a value of 100000 would actually be 0.1V, and 3827498 would be 3.827498 volts.  The mathematics at your prescribed resolution become precise, however you lack the ability to then represent 287x10<sup>36</sup>V without having massive variables to store the value.

Comment: Why does `echo 100 - 91.51` display 8.49 then? Is it rounded before it's output on the page?

Comment: Yup.  Try using `number_format()` on it to get more decimal places.

Comment: @Styphon - it's accurate to the level of precision defined in your php.ini file

Comment: That depends on what your previous work was.  Are you the reason NASA missed Mars years ago?

Comment: Might be true. Using the software I wrote for them, they might have calculated wrong number of light minutes.

Comment: There was a classic mistake while they were doing Star Wars research in the 80's when a terrain scanning program expected height data in miles and the data was actually input in metres.... not a floating point precision error, but hilariously funny when the space shuttle turned turtle and started hunting for the summit of Table Mountain somewhere 1,085 miles into space

Comment: Almost as good as the mixing newton-seconds and pound-seconds for the Mars climate orbiter in 1998/9...